# Is there the command in Mac OS X(10.8) equivalent to 'iptables'?

Tags: macos, osx-server

I want to reject some traffic in Mac OS X 10.8(Server) like using:

> iptables -t filter -I INPUT 4 -s xxx.xxx.xxx.0/20 -p tcp --dport 1723
>   -j REJECT

Is there the equivalent command for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With OS X 10.7, Apple deprecated use of FreeBSD's `ipfw` and switched to OpenBSD's `pf`.

The control command for `pf` is [`pfctl`(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pfctl.8.html).

You will find a brief discussion as of 10.7 [here](http://www.zomo.co.uk/2011/09/pf-on-os-x-10-7/). This is useful for highlighting a couple ways OS X's PF differs from the stock BSD version.

Documentation on PF is widely available, including Hansteen's *[The Book of PF](http://www.nostarch.com/pf2.htm).* The author also wrote a freely available [tutorial](http://home.nuug.no/~peter/pf/en/long-firewall.html), and the [OpenBSD documentation](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) is also freely available.

Note: If your machine is also running OS X Server under 10.8, you might need to [fix a config error](https://support.apple.com/kb/TS4418) that Apple made before PF starts working.

Comment: There's also an open-source GUI program for configuring pf: [Hanynet's IceFloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there the equivalent command for Mac OS X?

I don't believe so. They used to have `ipfw` and `ipfw6`, but that's been marked as deprecated. I have not been able to find a replacement either. See, for example, [Firewall and Blocking [More] Traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/664158/firewall-and-blocking-more-traffic).

Essentially, Apple has taken nearly all control away from the users.