# Equivalent iptables command on OS X 10.9

Tags: linux, macos, iptables, pf

I want to redirect the tcp traffic temporarily to a custom port. On Linux, I use the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1935 -m owner \! --uid-owner root -j REDIRECT
```

and to reverse the changes:

```
iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1935 -m owner \! --uid-owner root -j REDIRECT
```

They work just fine on Linux but sadly not on OS X. Can someone please give me the equivalent commands or methods that will work on OS X 10.9?

Comment: Take a look at `pf`: http://superuser.com/questions/688680/is-there-the-command-in-mac-os-x10-8-equivalent-to-iptables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime I try extending a configuration for **pf** from OpenBSD (which I use regularly) to MacOS, I fail miserably, so this time I will spare myself (and you) some embarrassment by skipping this step, and giving you a solution which uses *socat*, which you can install from macports (see [here](http://www.macports.org/) to learn more about macports and how to use it).

Basically, it is as simple as:

```
  sudo port install socat
```

and from there

```
  socat TCP-LISTEN:8888,fork TCP:www.nytimes.com:80
```

This redirects port 8888 (protocol TCP) to the New York Times' port 80. If you want to redirect to yourself, substitute *www.nytimes.com* with localhost*.